# MySQL Rolling SUM

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, rollup

For example I have the bellow table

```
 DATE       QUANTITY
9/10/2017     3
9/10/2016     5
9/03/2015     6
9/10/2017     2
8/10/2017     9
```

And I Want the final output to look like below

```
YEAR    MONTH   ROLLING SUM   SUM
2015     03          6         6
2016     10          11        5
2017     10          25        14
```

To get the sum I use the following code

```
SELECT YEAR(Date),MONTH(Date),SUM(QUANTITY) 
FROM table
GROUP BY YEAR(Date),MONTH(Date);
```

Is it possible to add the Rollup Sum to the same query?

As a second note:
At the moment I am using MySQL but the final enviroment that these queries  will be running is AWS Athena.And I was wondering if there is a middle ground between the two to test these queries.

Comment: You can use a JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most databases you can use window functions:

```
SELECT YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date), SUM(QUANTITY),
       SUM(SUM(QUANTITY)) OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(DATE), MONTH(DATE) 
FROM table
GROUP BY YEAR(Date),MONTH(Date);
```

In MySQL, I would recommend a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date), SUM(QUANTITY),
       (SELECT SUM(t2.QUANTITY)
        FROM table t2
        WHERE YEAR(t2.Date) < YEAR(t.Date) OR
              (YEAR(t2.Date) = YEAR(t.Date) AND MONTH(t2.Date) <= MONTH(t.date))
       ) as rolling_sum
FROM table t
GROUP BY YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date);
```